# Anchor tag works only in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

on my page I have a box named "okno1" with some text in it and on mouseover, a picture appears istead of that text, after cca 5sec text returns. The problem is, that the whole box "okno1" should be a link to another page, which works in in firefox. i Tried it like:

```
<a href=".." target="_blank"> 
    <okno1 id="okno1" onMouseOver="zobraz1();"> ...  </okno1>
</a>
```

after this i tried js:

```
<okno1  id="okno1" onclick="nahrejodkaz('....');" onMouseOver="zobraz1();"> .... </okno1>

function nahrejodkaz(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Both work only in firefox. Is there some way, how it could work in chrome and IE?

JS:

```
function zrus1() {
    document.getElementById("okno1").innerHTML ='CYKLOPRŮVODCE
    <br>Cyklistika';
}

function zobraz1(){
    var doba=3000;
    document.getElementById("okno1").innerHTML = '<img src="kolo.jpg"
    alt="Cyklistika" name="img">';
    window.setTimeout('zrus1();',doba);
}
```

CSS

```
okno1 {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiline strings in Javascript this way (more on the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript). After removing line breaks from strings, your example starts working in Chrome.

Comment: As `okno1` is a custom element, don't you need to register it as such?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand with my bad english, in my document, I have it like ...innerHTML ='CYKLOPRŮVODCE <br>Cyklistika'; (in 1 line). I tried to change it like var c ="....."; ...innerHTML = c , but it still doesn't work, the link is opened only in firefox

Comment: okno1 is one of many custom boxes which I have on my page, There's some need to register them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. I didn't bother to chase-down why exactly your attempt was failing. Differences include 
(0) attaching event handlers instead of using inline JS
(1) removing the mouseover handler for the okno1 element for the 5s period it has its content changed.

Works with Chrome, IE 11.Chrome displays the parent folder in the browser window, IE opens it in an Explorer window.

```js
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var okno1 = document.registerElement('okno-1'); // okno1 is an invalid tag-name
 byId('okno1').addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver, false);
}

function onMouseOver(evt)
{
 this.removeEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
 this.innerHTML = "<img src='kolo.jpg' alt='Cyklistika' name='img'>";

 window.setTimeout(onTimerElapsed, 5000);
}

function onTimerElapsed(evt)
{
 var tgt = byId('okno1');
 tgt.innerHTML = ' ...  ';
 tgt.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver, false);
}
```

```css
okno-1
{
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
}
```

```html
<a href=".." target="_blank"><okno-1 id="okno1"> ...  </okno-1></a>
```

Comment: Don't you need to register the custom element?

Comment: You _should_, but I'm yet to see their use fail when this has not been done. For more, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

Comment: As it's experimental, the assumption that it will continue to work without registering, means it may stop working in the future.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - that's a great point. One I must admit to not realize you were getting at. We all _love_ answers that cease working with time, due to sloppiness on the part of their provider. Thanks again, fixing, gimme 30 or 40 secs.

Comment: I don't rly understand how it works, but it works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.okno1 { 
     display:block;
     width:250px;
     height:250px; 
     float:left;
     border: 1px solid blue; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
          <a class="okno1" href="new_page.html" target="_blank">
          <p id="okno1" onMouseOver="zobraz1();">hello</p>    
     </a>    
   </div>
<script>
    function zrus1(){
    document.getElementById("okno1").innerHTML ='HELLO';
    }

    function zobraz1(){
    var doba=3000;
    document.getElementById("okno1").innerHTML = '<img src="kolo.png" alt="Cyklistika" name="img">';
    window.setTimeout('zrus1()',doba);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's more simple than the previous one. However, with the previous one, the code doesn't "blinking" if you look at it as on www. page... and the picture stays as long as you have mouse cursor on the box, which is better, so I rather use that